# how do i import from a unicode (utf-8) csv file into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

im not trying to do this smart or fast, just trying to do it at all.

i have a file looks like this :

```
$ cat all_user_token_counts.csv  
@5raphaels,in,15
@5raphaels,for,15
@5raphaels,unless,11
@5raphaels,you,11
```

i know its uncode utf-8 encoded because i created it, like this

```
    debug('opening ' + ALL_USER_TOKEN_COUNTS_FILE)
    file = codecs.open(ALL_USER_TOKEN_COUNTS_FILE, encoding="utf-8",mode= "w")
    for (user, token) in tokenizer.get_tokens_from_all_files():
        #... count tokens ..
        file.write(unicode(username +","+ token +","+ str(count) +"\r\n"))
```

i want to read it in to a numpy array so it looks like this, or something..

```
   array([[u'@5raphaels', u'in', 15],
          [u'@5raphaels', u'for', 11],
          [u'@5raphaels', u'unless', 11]], 
          dtype=('<U10', '<U10', int))
```

As i experiment in process of writing this question it comes to me that it may not even be possible? If so, I'd love to know!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: realised my real problem was that i was trying to use different data types in the one array - and I dont think Numpy likes that, ultimately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done easily with [np.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt):

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.loadtxt('all_user_token_counts.csv',delimiter=',',
                  dtype = '|U10,<U10,int')
print(arr)

# [(u'@5raphaels', u'in', 15) (u'@5raphaels', u'for', 15)
#  (u'@5raphaels', u'unless', 11) (u'@5raphaels', u'you', 11)]
```

Comment: This, unfortunately, throws `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte...`